# How can I use a constructor (explicit) to convert a int type to a class?

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I must create a code that uses an explicit constructor to convert a int type to an existing class.

```
class MyClass
{public:
    MyClass(int& obj);  //I tried to use a syntax similar to a copy construct
}


int a;
MyClass a();
```

Comment: That's not an explicit constructor. Why does it take a non-const reference? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit

Comment: also, `MyClass a();` should be `MyClass myclass{a};`

Comment: Before asking a question, it might be a good idea to read a book to get some basic knowledge (or review your course note); By the way `MyClass a();`would declare a function named `a` that would return an object of type `MyClass` if called. It will not construct an object as you might think: [Most vexing parse](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2018/01/30/most-vexing-parse/).

Comment: I see: 1) a lack of a question in the question itself, 2) a lack of an `explicit` constructor, and 3) no attempt to construct a class from an `int`. You might be jumping the gun, attempting to use certain tools before understanding what they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cpp
class MyClass
{
private:
    int m_value;
public:
    explicit MyClass(int value) : m_value(value) {}
};
```

```cpp
int a = ...;
MyClass obj(a);
```